# Filtrar um tipo NULL em lambda expression ou linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api, expressões-lambda

Olá, minha entidade **A** tem um atributo do tipo long que pode ser **NULL** fazendo relacionamento com a entidade **B**, ao fazer um filtro com uma expressão Lambda com esse atributo para trazer todos os registros que são diferentes de **NULL** ele não reconhece a minha condição **WHERE** e acaba retornando todos os objetos da entidade. 
Segue a consulta.

```
return Context.MatriculaInscricaoAluno.Where(p => p.TituloID != null ).Count();
```

em syntax SQL Server funciona da seguinte maneira.

```
select * from Siscona.MatriculaInscricaoAluno where TituloID is NULL
```

obrigado a todos.

Comment: o tipo deve ser `long?` certo ? Tente: `Where(p => p.TituloID.HasValue)`

Comment: acho que no SQL, seria `is not null`

Comment: Opá, infelizmente nada.

Comment: Coloca seu como está, um exemplo mínimo verificável por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode fazer a comparação direto do seu objeto:

```
return Context.MatriculaInscricaoAluno.Where(p => p.Titulo == null).ToList().Count();
```

Comment: Infelizmente nada amigo.

Comment: então coloca: "".Where(p=>p.TituloID.Value == null || p.TituloID.Value == 0)